# How to check all asp.net checkboxes on single asp.net button click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

How to check all asp.net checkboxes on single asp.net button click event

if i have 45 checkboxes inside panel1 i want on button click event all the checkboxes will be checked and on another button click event all checkboxes will be unchecked...

how to do it using jquery, javascript or vb.net ?

Answer (score 2):

With jQuery you can do

```
var $checkboxes = $('input[type=checkbox]');
$('#check').toggle(function() {
    $checkboxes.attr('checked', 'checked');
    return false;

}, function() {
    $checkboxes.removeAttr('checked');
    return false;
});
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/zgTw3/5/

Comment: It doesn't matter what server side language you are using. Make sure jQuery is loaded before the code. You can also try to wrap the code with a document ready function $(function(){..})

Answer (score 0):

This is your aspx file code for checkboxes, panel and button;

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">

    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" />
    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox3" runat="server" />

</asp:Panel>
<asp:Button Text="click" ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" />
```

And this is your c# code for **button click event** event;

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    foreach (Control c in Panel1.Controls) {

        if (c is CheckBox) {

            (c as CheckBox).Checked = true;
        }

    }
}
```

this is the VB version of this c# code;

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    For Each c As Control In Panel1.Controls

        If TypeOf c Is CheckBox Then

            TryCast(c, CheckBox).Checked = True

        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

when you click the button, it should check all the checkboxes in bulk.

**EDIT :**

if you wanna check the unchecked ones and uncheck the checked ones on the same click, do the following

C# :

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        foreach (Control c in Panel1.Controls) {

            if (c is CheckBox) {

                if ((c as CheckBox).Checked) {

                    (c as CheckBox).Checked = false;

                } else {

                    (c as CheckBox).Checked = true;
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

VB :

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    For Each c As Control In Panel1.Controls

        If TypeOf c Is CheckBox Then

            If TryCast(c, CheckBox).Checked Then


                TryCast(c, CheckBox).Checked = False
            Else

                TryCast(c, CheckBox).Checked = True
            End If

        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: it willl only check all checkboxes not uncheck all checkboxes i want both event check and unchec ..and also the page will be refreshed ...

Comment: @pooja it certainly refreshes the page. do you want to check the unchecked ones and uncheck the checked ones on the same click?

Comment: @pooja I edited my answer in order to check the unchecked ones and uncheck the checked ones on the same click.

Comment: surely, something like this (has to) can be done client-side, don't you think?

Comment: @pooja of course. @Hussein has already given this example. that would be verbosity to give the same answer again, don't you think? I just wanted to explore the options here.

Comment: @Richard, the above answer were meant to you. @pooja, sorry for that :s

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET has a bit of a quirk when it comes to rendering `ID`s and `NAME`s on its controls.

Try something like this instead:

```
<asp:Button ID="myToggleButton" runat="server" Text="Toggle Checkboxes" />
```

and then in your script

```
$('[id$="myToggleButton"]').click(function(){
    $('input:checkbox')
         .filter(':checked')
         .attr('checked',false)
         .end()
         .not(':checked')
         .attr('checked',true)
         ;        
});
```

or something along the same idea. I'm pretty sure you can optimize that jQuery code a bit more.